# list of scikit-learn algorithms requiring standardization/normalization

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science

Can some one please provide list of all algorithms which needs data to be standardized or normalized before use Or can someone please tell me with example where can I find it in scikit-learn documentation.

Comment: There is no distinct "requires"/"requires not" answer to this question. For example a neural network will function with scaled or non-scaled data, but might profit from standardization. Hence, you rather need a discussion which algorithm profits in which scenario from standarization/normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases feature scaling means that:
1. Make the mean values of all features not too large (say, 0)
2. Make the variance of all features roughly the same (say, 1)

So your question can be asked slightly differently:
1) which algorithms depend on absolute values near zero?
2) which algorithms require values to be distributed comparably?
3) which algorithms use regularization that penalize extreme weights of features?

The 1st point is tightly related to activation functions in ANN which has a maximal learning capabilities near zero (sigmoid, tanh, relu) due to derivatives.

The 2nd and the 3rd point are related to equality of weights of different features.

In general due to the 2nd and the 3rd points you should always make scaling. The exception is decision trees which doesn't use any joint metrics with different features nor any assumptions on mean value and thus can be used without scaling.

Comment: Hey can you tell me that how to find answers of above three questions

Comment: You need to exactly know what are you doing. Regarding to classification or regression use scaling in all cases except for decision trees. For clustering I think the same, but you need to check the implementation of the algorithm. You can just compare the results with and without scaling — if they are same, then it's likely that absolute values and variance do not matter, in another case use scaling.